# Can a Chrome extension utilize client storage

Tags: javascript, database, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, client-side

I have a Google Chrome extension that needs to check to see what url the client is viewing to determine some behavior, but the behavior varies significantly depending on the url.

It varies in such a way that the most useful type of data-structure to use would be analogous to a database with urls as the primary key.

Is it possible to utilize client storage for this? I would like to just have the database loaded when the browser itself loads, so the extension can just get its information from there, rather than having to load a huge DS in an event page.

I would think this would  be possible, but the stuff I am reading about client storage says it is allocated based on url.

So, is it possible for my Google Chrome extension to utilize client storage, if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of options.

Good old `localStorage` is bound to *origin*, not URL. For internal pages of your extension, e.g. background page, it will always be `chrome-extension://<your-id-here>/`. This will not be the case for content scripts, but you can use background page as a "server" for data storage with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

A better option is [`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). It provides access to the same storage to both extension scripts and content scripts.

Both of those options are key-value stores. If you need a proper database, you have more options.

Obvious one is [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). I suppose it's also bound to domain, so again your background page should be doing the storage access, and content scripts (if any) will have to message it.

Another solution is [WebDatabase](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/), a specification that is no longer on standards track but Chrome will probably not drop support for it for a while. Same same-origin

A slightly more exotic one would be to use [HTML FileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to host any DB you want - e.g. SQLite. Again, this is a non-cross-browser solution but Chrome will probably continue to support it.

Comment: Hey thanks, I think I am going to go with chrome.storage, but can you answer how I would go about creating the database? the one thing I am confused about is where I set the values. I want to create a databse that is just created when the app is downloaded, or each time the broser is opened. (the former if possible, the latter if not), so I dont want to be initializing the DB in an event page or in a content script right?